# Why won't addActionListener(e -> {...}); not work, when making it listen to a private void?

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I have looked around for quite a while now, and can't seem to find an answer for what I was looking for.
I used to work BlueJ, but my new school is using IntelliJ, but not everything is working the same way, like I remember it.

I have a `private void tester()`, that I'm placing inside an `testButton.addActionListener(e -> {tester();});`.
When I'm starting my program, I get an error immediately, but the program still opens, but when I click the button, nothing happens but a long error appears.
The first errors that appears is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
>       at FrameTest.(FrameTest.java:16)
>       at FrameTest.main(FrameTest.java:11)

Then when I click the button, this long error appears:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
>       at FrameTest.tester(FrameTest.java:30)
>       at FrameTest.lambda$makeFrame$0(FrameTest.java:47)
>       at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
>       at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
>       at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
>       at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
>       at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
>       at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6632)
>       at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
>       at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6397)
>       at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
>       at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5008)
>       at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
>       at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
>       at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
>       at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
>       at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
>       at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
>       at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
>       at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
>       at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
>       at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
>       at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
>       at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
>       at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
>       at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
>       at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
>       at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
>       at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
>       at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
>       at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
>       at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
>       at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
>       at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>       at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

I don't know if the long errors helps, but wanted to display them.

Here is my entire code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.*;

public class FrameTest {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JLabel test;
    private String liste[] =  new String[1];
    private int number = 0;
    public static void main (String[] args){
        new FrameTest();
    }
    public FrameTest(){
        makeFrame();
        liste[0] = "[**********]";
        liste[1] = "[*********-]";  //line 16, which caused the exception 
        liste[2] = "[********--]";
        liste[3] = "[*******---]";
        liste[4] = "[******----]";
        liste[5] = "[*****-----]";
        liste[6] = "[****------]";
        liste[7] = "[***-------]";
        liste[8] = "[**--------]";
        liste[9] = "[*---------]";
        liste[10] = "[----------]";
    }

    private void tester(){
        number++;
        test.setText(liste[number]);
    }

    private void makeFrame(){
        frame = new JFrame("Test");
        JPanel contentPane = (JPanel)frame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(1, 60, 1, 60));

        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(12, 12));

        JPanel testPanel = new JPanel();
        testPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));

        test = new JLabel("[**********]");
        testPanel.add(test);

        JButton testButton = new JButton("Test");
        testButton.addActionListener(e -> {tester();});
        testPanel.add(testButton);

        contentPane.add(testPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();

        Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        frame.setLocation(d.width/2 - frame.getWidth()/2, d.height/2 - frame.getHeight()/2);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `liste` has a size of 1, so only the index `0` exists.

Comment: Welcome to SO. **"I don't know if the long errors helps"** yes, it does. It is a good practice to post the exception stack trace. Also marking the relevant row , `FrameTest.java:16` in this case, with a comments, to show the the line which caused the exception, helps.

Comment: There are at least two errors in your code. First, you create the array `liste` to have size **1**. But then your code tries to set slots from 0 to 10. And then you use that number variable as index, and you keep incrementing it. Simply cant work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

increase the size of your String array to a proper length, e.g. in your case:

```
    private String liste[] =  new String[11]; // can store eleven elements
```

and to avoid `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` beeing thrown after clicking your button multiple times (more than 11 times), you should check the index in your `tester()` method:

```
private void tester(){
    if(number<liste.length) {
        number++;
    }
    test.setText(liste[number]);  //if number is greater than liste.length this would lead to an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException!
}
```

Comment: Thanks, next time I should look through my code some more, so I don't make a stupid mistake like that. I really thought I did something wrong in the addActionListener()

Answer (score -2):

Tester is not an ActionListener, its a method.

try

```
addActionlistener(        new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
           //put code for what tester does here. 
            tester();
        }
    }
```

Comment: And this doesn't answer the question, by far. And: it is simply wrong: he adds the test method as **lambda** . So that part is fully correct. You should either improve your answer or delete it, no middle ground here.

Comment: I know its not an ActionListener, the method needs to be called by an ActionListener.

Comment: Read the question. It says: `testButton.addActionListener(e -> {tester();});` . As said: all fine (regarding that part). The code is adding an action listener.

Comment: Oh yea, you defined the array to be [1]